# How to let DropboxAPI work in runModalForWindow

Tags: cocoa, dropbox, nswindow

I'm using the Dropbox API for OSX. All works fine, except when I want to make calls in a modal window that is started with [NSApp runModalForWindow:thisWindow]; it seems the modal loop blocks the 
DropboxAPI from processing anything.
The DBRestClient delegate methods are never called in response to for example [client loadMetadata:path]; Which is - if understand correctly - in line with what the NSApplication documentation says for this method. The question is:
Is there a way to let calls to Dropbox work from inside a modal window?
I have seen that timers can be added to the NSModalPanelRunLoopMode. Is there perhaps something similar for the DroboxAPI?

And additionally: will Dropbox calls that were started but not yet completed before this or any other modal window is displayed proceed as normal, or are they also blocked?

Yes; further investigation shows any runModalForWindow and even displaying an NSAlert.showModal will completely block the DropboxAPI. Also, inplace mouse handling loops do the same thing. Imo a major design flaw in the OSX DropboxAPI: it should have been running on a background thread. The only way around this, is to not start *any* user task that could involve blocking Dropbox while the API something is still running. Which is not really feasible in any non-trivial app that needs dropbox to work in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of NSApplication runModalForWindow is indeed too harsh.

Here is more humanistic version:

```
void runWindowModal(NSWindow* pnw) {

        [pnw retain];

        NSApplication* app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];

        NSModalSession session = [app beginModalSessionForWindow:pnw];

        for( ;; ) {
          if ([app runModalSession:session] != NSModalResponseContinue)
             break;

          NSEvent* e = [app nextEventMatchingMask: NSAnyEventMask
                                        untilDate: [NSDate distantFuture]
                                           inMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                          dequeue: YES];
          if (e != nil)
           [app sendEvent: e];
        }

        [app endModalSession: session];

        [pnw release];

}
```

This will enable NSURLConnection and other callbacks processing while running modal loops.

Comment: Added this not exactly for you but to other people who may bump into this in future.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox support just confirmed that the DropboxAPI on OSX works on the main runloop and indeed runModalForWindow etc. will block the API. There's no work around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more general. All nsurl connections can run only on the main runloop. This means that webviews have the same issue. And there is a sollution to this. You have to create a modal session and run it for short amounts of time, frequently, and lock the main thread in a loop until the modal window is closed. Every time you switch back to the modal session, the main runloop will finish any scheduled tasks, and that includes the nsurlconnections from the modal session.

Now I will show you a piece of code but note that this is c# using Xamarin.Mac library. You should be able to translate this easily to objc. But if you find it difficult, you can look up solutions for nswebview in modal dialog.

```
//so this is in my NSWindowController - the modal dialog
IntPtr session;
bool running;

public void showDialog ()//this is the method I use to show the dialog
{
    running = true;
    session = NSApplication.SharedApplication.BeginModalSession (Window);
    int resp = (int)NSRunResponse.Continues;

    while (running && resp == (int)NSRunResponse.Continues) {
        resp = (int)NSApplication.SharedApplication.RunModalSession (session);
        NSRunLoop.Current.RunUntil (NSRunLoopMode.Default, NSDate.DistantFuture);
    }
    NSApplication.SharedApplication.EndModalSession (session);
}

[Export ("windowWillClose:")]
public void WindowWillClose (NSNotification notification)//this is the override of windowWillClose:
{
    running = false;
}
```